# Is there an Integration platform which is open source and free even for a lot of data, for unlimited runs and flows?

Tags: rest, integration

From my understanding, Informatica Cloud, Boomi, Talend, JitterBit are all integration tools which have "Connectors" to connect to servers (and I believe these Connectors in turn call APIs to access the required data). I saw many others but none of them are free although some are open source.
Are there any tools that help you visualize the integration process for free? If not, why not?

Tools like Informatica, Boomi provide drag and drop which show the entire flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talend Open Studio is one such tool. not completely visual but almost there.

There are not many free tools as data storage technologies are constantly changing. It would be expensive for developers to keep up with constantly changing technologies without a source of income.

Answer (score 0):

Developing data integration tools are resource intensive. Why would anybody(any enterprise company) spend so much of their effort and give away for free. Also the provider of the tools have to provide support for enterprise level . P1 means 4 hour response which means building the capability of the support team on par with the developer. All of these cost money and time. The only way to recoup is to sell the finished product and provide services.